# KML does not open correctly in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, kml

I have a KML file that I'm trying to open on QGIS. However, when I add them in QGIS I obtain a raster and a polygon but the raster do not fit in the polygon.

I guess the polygon contain geovalue while the raster do not. How can I manage that?

[image]

Comment: Which CRS both layers possess? Bring them both into one.